# slickjs how to remove gaps at edges

Tags: javascript, slick.js

In slickjs, how can I remove the gaps at the edge of the carousel when the arrorws are turned off?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap your slick.js element with a row (use bootstrap's `row` class or write your own, if needed).

Example here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XgEyej (a piece of markup below)

```
<div class="slick-with-no-gaps">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="slick"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The negative margins, `margin-left` and `margin-right`, of the wrapper element will stretch the element inside, as seen in the example.

Comment: OK this is a possible solution, but where did you get the -15px margin from? Thanks!

Comment: Check out the codepen example in the post. You can adjust the margin values to anything you want.